# >= and <= signs getting error in thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, if-statement, thymeleaf

The following javascript compound if condition cannot be processed in thymeleaf although I wrapped it in "CDATA".

```
<script  th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
         if(value =< 0 && value >= 100){
              return 'Please enter a value between 0 to 100';
         }
 /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I am getting error: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"`

Comment: You are looking for `<=`. `=<` doesn't exist. Funny that you are using the correct operator in the title of question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less than or equal to is `<=`
Greater than or equal to is `>=`

I think you have the wrong token when you write `=<` instead of `<=`